# no auth login ssh for local development

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sshd

I'm trying to set up a local development environment without any password whatsoever.
I use docker with a default container with the sshd service installed.
My idea is to spread the docker box to our team and remove all password promts form the login command.

I tried to add a default pubkey to the authorized_keys file, but the ssh service always seems to look for the id_rsa file.
I can't serve my id_rsa key for another pc obviously.
So either i need to figure out how to make ssh look for another key file or i completely disable the password promt, but i cant find any usefull informations for that.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Since it was a bit confusing for some:
I need an ssh connection to a server without the generation of a public key on the local machine. My global goal is to just disable the password promt and allow all users to be logged in without a password.

I **don't** care about how **secure** it is because we are using those containers only for local development.

Best Regards,
and thanks in advance

EDIT:

temporary soluton is

```
sshpass -p mypassword ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 2222 user@server sh myfile.sh
```

Comment: Use [this guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E37125/sshuser-12.html) for host based authentication.

Answer (score 0):

### Disclaimer: this soulution is not something one would want to implement on his production servers.

To totally get rid of ssh authentication you need to put below lines in your Dockerfile:

```
RUN echo "PermitEmptyPasswords yes" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Above is self-explanatory.

```
RUN echo "PermitRootLogin yes" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Above is self-explanatory.

```
RUN echo "StrictHostKeyChecking no" >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

Disables presenting target's public key fingerprint to the user - no need to take any action of accept/reject.

```
RUN passwd -d root
```

Removes current password from root user (default user for docker).

---

Last one is tricky. Technically you don't have password assigned to the `root` at the beginning. But if you look into `/etc/shadow` file, you'll notice it's not empty either:

```
root:*:18855:0:99999:7:::
```

The asterisk ruins everything. If you run the last command, you'll get:

```
root::18855:0:99999:7:::
```

which only then is consiedered an **empty password**.

Sources:

1. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sshd_config.5.html
2. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh.1.html
3. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/shadow.5.html

Answer (score -3):

What you need to do is:

1. Generate an authentication key-pair

Using either ssh-keygen on a Unix based box or PuTTYGen if on Windows - generate a new key-pair. For example, using ssh-keygen on unix type

```
ssh-keygen -b 4096
```

Press enter to use the default names (id_rsa and id_rsa.pub). I think for your scenario you'd want to just hit enter when asked for a passphrase (**Note** this won't be as secure!).

Your keys will then be generated and placed in /home/your_username/.ssh.

2. Upload generated public key to container
   Again the actual steps will vary depending on OS, but copy the public key (one ending in .pub - SCP can be used on Linux to copy file) and place them in the /home/your_username/.ssh/authorized_keys/ directory (creating this path if needed).
3. Set permissions on public key directory and key file (Linux)
   Set the permissions on the .ssh folder to something like 700
   I.E. `sudo chmod 700 .ssh`
   And set the permissions on the actual keys to something like 600
   I.E. `sudo chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys`

Sorry if that was a bit of a whistlestop tour, I'd suggest looking at instructions such as those found at Linode under 'securing your server' https://www.linode.com/docs/security/securing-your-server/ and the "Create an Authentication Key-Pair" section. Or for Windows http://www.servermom.org/passwordless-ssh-login/1608/ which also gives a bit more background.

This also has been answered a few times in the past on StackOverflow if you do a search ;)

Comment: thats exactly not what i need :) i want to avoid the key generation on the user side, since docker runs trough a script provisioner. I need a Method to connect to a server without any authentication (no password / no pub keys). It doesn't have to be secure since we only use this for local development.

Comment: It comes down to how your docker image is configured then.  Are you using one created/supplied by someone else?

Are you looking for something like https://github.com/jeroenpeeters/docker-ssh ?

Comment: I have tried that out, but its to much of a hassle, i configure the containers by my self. I ended up using sshpass in my commands with the o StrictHostKeyChecking=no flag in my ssh commands